# Smartphone Fast Charger with Lipo and UBEC

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I have a 3 cell, 11.1V Lipo and a 5V@3A UBEC that I am using to charge my Samsung S8+ with USB type C cable.

This works fine, but my phone reports "slow charging" and takes about an hour to charge 10%. If I use the phone while its charging this way, I will **still slowly lose power**.

When I plug the cable into the "fast charger" provided by Samsung, the phone will charge from 0% to 100% in about 40 minutes.

The adapter for the fast charger reports `9.0V@1.67A OR 5.0V@2.0A`

Shouldn't a 5v@3A UBEC be able to match or beat this speed? How does my phone know that one is the fast charger and the other isn't?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Shouldn't a 5v@3A UBEC be able to match or beat this speed?*

Indeed the amount of **power** (15W) is enough **but** the **phone** determines if it will fast charge or not.

*How does my phone know that one is the fast charger and the other isn't?*

Indeed your phone does not recognize the UBEC as being capable of providing the power so the phone does not "know" it can draw 3 A at 5 V. Very likely it also **cannot** draw 3 A at 5 V, it will need 9 V for the fastest charging and converts that 9V into a lower voltage which also increases the current (using a switched power converter).

The phone and the official Samsung charger communicate through the data lines in the USB cable, the charger puts some voltages on those lines and the phone detects that. Obviously the UBEC charger doesn't do that so the phone plays it safe and assumes that it can only draw a modest current making charging slow.

If you used a USB cable to connect to the UBEC module, what you can do is **short** the two datalines, usually these are the green and white cables. Then maybe the phone sees the UBEC as a charger and it might charge faster. I have used this trick (shorting the datalines) many times before and it often helps to increase the charging current. It does depend on the phone if this will work though so no guarantees!

Answer (score 0):

UBEC only has two ports positive and GND. For fast charging a power source needs to process data through the other 2 data wires which UBEC doesn't has. This is why it can't power up well.